# Fourier series of $\cos(\pi w x)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $w\notin \mathbb{Z}$, calculate the fourier series of $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \cos(\pi wx)$ where the period is $2$.

---

My attempt:

Previously, I have calculated the coefficients for a function $f^*:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with period $L$:
$$f^*(x)\sim a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos(\frac{2\pi nx}{L})+b_n\sin(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}))$$
which are
\begin{align*}
&a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^{\frac{2}{L}}_{-\frac{2}{L}} f^*(x)\cos(\frac{2\pi nx}{L})dx\\
&b_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^{\frac{2}{L}}_{-\frac{2}{L}} f^*(x)\sin(\frac{2\pi nx}{L})dx
\end{align*}

So I think I can look at $f(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi w x}{2})$ since the period is $2$, right? I also know that $\cos$ is an even function, so $b_n = 0$ $\forall n$

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
f(x)\sim a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos(\frac{2\pi nx}{2})+b_n\sin(\frac{2\pi nx}{2}))
\end{align*}
with coefficients
\begin{align*}
&a_n = \int^{1}_{-1} \cos(\pi w x)\cos(\pi nx)dx\\
&b_n = 0
\end{align*}
$$\Rightarrow \quad f(x)\sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int^{1}_{-1} \cos(\pi w y)\cos(\pi ny)dy)\cdot \cos(\pi nx)$$

Is this correct? Can/should I simplify further?

EDIT: I used $\cos(x)\cos(y)=\frac{1}{2} (\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y))$ and can simplify further:

$$\Rightarrow \quad f(x)\sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin(\pi (n-w))}{\pi (n-w)}+\frac{sin(\pi(n+w))}{\pi(n+w)})\cdot \cos(\pi nx)$$

Comment: The last formula can lead to confusion. Don't use $x$ for the integration value. Also, use $\cos a\cos b=\frac12[\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b)]$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the tipp, but I suppose you mean $\cos(x)\cos(y) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y))$? I've edited the question and would like to ask you again if it's correct since I have no solutions to verify the result.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Note that $n,w\in\mathbb Z$, so all the sine terms are zero, unless $n=w$ or $n=-w$

Comment: @Andrei but $w\notin \mathbb{Z}$ according to the question.

Comment: I've missed that part. But then how can the period be 2?

Comment: @Andrei good question! Must be a mistake from my professor. I'll carry on from here, thank you very much for all your help :)